# Change .NET Framework in Integration Services Project

Tags: ssis, ssdt-bi

When creating a new Integration Services Project in Visual Studio 2013 I can select the .NET framework to target. How can I see what .NET framework is being targeted on an existing project and potentially change it?

Comment: SSIS projects don't target a specific .NET framework. The framework dropdown you see when creating a new project only filters the project templates in the dialog.

Comment: For script task you can change ,when you open script that is like your .net project only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open one of the Script Tasks and click the "Edit script..." button. This will open the script on a new instance of Visual Studio with the script in its own project. There you can change the properties of that project to modify the targeted framework for that particular Script Task.

Comment: it gets reverted any time you close it.

Comment: You must remember to hit save when you modify the script project.

Comment: Even pressing Save (assuming you mean the small blue icon or "Save Selected Items") does not stop it from reverting upon exit, at least that is what I am seeing in VS2019. This is not the correct answer for this reason - @JWeezy's answer is the truth.

Answer (score 1):

There is no .NET Framework targeting for SSIS packages. However, there IS SQL Server version targeting. Prior to Visual Studio (VS) 2015, it was a bit of a mess: you could only target a specific version of SQL Server with a specific version of Visual Studio. For example:

- SQL 2008 = VS 2008
- SQL 2012 = VS 2012
- SQL 2014 = VS 2013

With the release of VS 2015, however, Microsoft alleviated some of the headache by introducing SQL Server targeting within VS by just right clicking on the solution, going to properties, and selecting the version of SQL Server that the SSIS package would run on. This is important because it determines what components are available to use.

Now, with that being said, there is .NET Framework targeting within script tasks/components. To read more about that, check my answer at:

[SSIS Script Keeps Reverting To .Net Framework 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629156/ssis-script-keeps-reverting-to-net-framework-4-5)