# Set .NET Framework version for ScriptComponentProject

Tags: biml

Is it possible to set the .NET Framework version for a `ScriptComponentProject`?

Currently it defaults to `.NET 4`, but I want it to be `.NET 4.6.1`

I've looked on the documentation page for `ScriptComponentProject` (https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Samples/Biml/Script+Component+Project), but without any luck.

Comment: I asked a similar question with respect to an SSIS Project. Here is the answer I got... https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288894/632537

Comment: Would also really like an answer to this

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found the answer!  You need to set the Target Framework Version in your script project:

https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Language/Element/AstComponentScriptProjectNode

And I think the available values are these:

Unspecified
Unspecified .NET Framework Version

NetFX20
.NET Framework 2.0

NetFX30
.NET Framework 3.0

NetFX35
.NET Framework 3.5

NetFX40
.NET Framework 4.0

NetFX45
.NET Framework 4.5

NetFX451
.NET Framework 4.5.1

NetFX452
.NET Framework 4.5.2

NetFX46
.NET Framework 4.6

NetFX461
.NET Framework 4.6.1

Which can be found here:  https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Api/Enum/ScriptProjectTargetFrameworkVersion

Comment: Hi, this property is not working for me on BIMLExpress  5.0.61915.0 with Visual Studio 2015 (the free version). What version are you using? can you share some sample code please?

Comment: @MSBI-Geek  I think this is something you would be better taking up with Varigence support over at support@varigence.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BIMLExpress 5.0.6xxx, you have probably faced the same issue.

I opened the generated .dtsx package and found that the **TargetFrameworkVersion** node placed inside of a separate **PropertyGroup** node. After I had moved it out to the first **PropertyGroup** of the same **arrayElement** node, then reopened my package in Visual Studio again, issue was gone! So you can write a script to move **TargetFrameworkVersion** node into the proper place for now.

Varigence support team told me that a public preview release is coming late next week which will include a fix for that (+also VS2017 support!).