# BIML - How to set .NET Framework version in a Script project using BIMLExpress

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm creating script tasks in SSIS packages using the free BIMLExpress. Since we have different versions of .NET Framework installed in our environment I really need to be able to set the Framework version for the script project. Although I know how to change it manually, it would be very difficult to change it manually.

> I have already tried looking for a solution and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825738/set-net-framework-version-for-scriptcomponentproject) suggests to use TargetFrameworkVersion property but I don't see that property at all, I've tried using it with no effect. I don't know if it only works with BimlStudio the paid version.

I'm using BIMLExpress 5.0.61915.0 with Visual Studio 2015.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I opened the generated .dtsx package and found that the **TargetFrameworkVersion** node placed inside of a separate **PropertyGroup** node. After I had moved it out to the first **PropertyGroup** of the same **arrayElement** node, then reopened my package in Visual Studio again, issue was gone! So you can write a script to move **TargetFrameworkVersion** node into the proper place for now.

Varigence support team told me that a public preview release is coming late next week which will include a fix for that.