# Breakpoint is not showing for SSIS script task with VS 2015

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package with script task, and is created in VS 2015. I am able to edit script task and opens in VISTA (VstaProjects), set a break point and shows there. But when I close the VstaProjects solution, the breaskpoint disappears in Scripttask in dts package and if I run the task in debug never hits the break point. I am using,

- SQL Server Data tool : 14.0.61712.050
- SQL Server Integration servcie Designed 14.0.1000.169
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 v 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to the problem of breakpoints not saving in the project: ReSharper might be causing this issue if you have it installed.

For me, disabling "Debugger Integration" in ReSharper options fixed breakpoints not being saved when closing the VSTA project.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the break-point, you must build the solution; save it; close VSTA; then click on OK. Failure to do any of these steps will wipe out the breakpoint.

See my answer here for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49640300/4630376