# Can't change .Net Framework in SSIS package

Tags: .net, ssis

We currently use Visual Studio 2012 for our development, but I've been tasked with moving everything to Visual Studio 2017 and upping the .Net framework on everything. So, I'm opening an SSIS package with Visual Studio 2017 on a Windows 10 machine. The machine is Windows 10 1803, so my understanding is that it has .Net 4.7.2 already installed. The SSIS package I'm using as my test case is currently using .Net 4.5. I want to change it to 4.6.1. I open the package in VS2017. I open a Script Task on the Control Flow and click on Edit Script. When the VSTA Editor opens, I go to Project and click on the project's properties. I change the .Net framework under Target Framework, build, save, return to VS2017, click OK on the Script Task Editor (all as described in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629156/ssis-script-keeps-reverting-to-net-framework-4-5), and rebuild my project. I close it, close VS2017, and then reopen. The .Net framework is back to 4.5. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Updating" packages is always dicey when it comes to SSIS. I'd recommend you take a look at this question on the MSDN forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f0bef4a-c571-4e97-a191-377ea4e3e7f8/ssis-script-component-not-updating-net-framework-after-2012-to-2017-upgrade?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: That *used* to work but I can confirm what you're experiencing. I'll see if I can ping some MS folks but if your company has a support contract, they'll likely respond faster than my peeps

Comment: What's the reasoning behind upping the .net framework version of your SSIS packages?

Comment: @digital.aaron - thanks for the link. It looks like it's an outstanding issue. And your question as to the motivation behind upping the version is a good one. The answer would be "Why not?" and this problem may provide a rationale for not changing the version. Unless I find a solution to this problem, I'm going to leave our SSIS packages at 4.5. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @billinkc - thank you for confirming I'm not nuts. I don't think this justifies spending money w/Microsoft, but if you hear anything, please let me know.

Comment: I believe I've solved this. If I do everything I described above but DO NOT delete the Script Task when I'm done, the change to the .Net Framework is saved. I don't remember this being the case with earlier versions of Visual Studio. Can someone confirm/deny?

Answer (score 0):

See the question and answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924746/220997

Starting with SQL Server 2017 framework version is based on SSIS project target server version:

- SQL Server 2017 enforces .Net framework 4.5
- SQL Server 2019 enforces .Net framework 4.7

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/release-notes-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15