# change target framework to net 5 in ssis 2019 script task

Tags: .net, ssis, visual-studio-2019, script-task, ssis-2019

I am trying to change the target framework for my SSIS 2019 script task to [.NET 5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral) from .NET 4.7 by installing other frameworks. My changes are reverted back to .NET 4.7 once I save and close out from the script task. Could you please guide me on how to make my changes stick or the ideal way to switch the target framework to **.NET 5.0**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSIS Script Keeps Reverting To .Net Framework 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629156/ssis-script-keeps-reverting-to-net-framework-4-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This is by design!

Since SSIS 2017, you are not able to change the script task/component's target framework since it is forced by the SSIS `TargetServerVersion` property. As mentioned in the following post, this is by design: [Script Task Target Framework - Cannot Change or Save](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/script-task-target-framework-cannot-change-or-save/321867).

Later, In the [SSIS extension version 3.2 preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects), they mentioned that:

> Upgraded .NET framework version to 4.7 for script task/component when the target server version is SQL Server 2019

This means that using SQL Server 2019 as `TargetServerVersion` will force .NET framework 4.7 as target framework for all script tasks/components.

---

You can check more information about SQL Server and required .NET framework versions in the following article:

- [Understand the .NET Framework requirements for various versions of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/install/understanding-dotnet-framework-requirements)