# Maximum supported .NET version in a script task in SSIS

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

Is there a hard binding of the maximum supported .NET version in a script task in SSIS. I am currently looking for such official information for SQL Server 2022 and cannot find it. Or maybe the .NET version can be the one installed? So could .NET 4.8 be the target version for SSIS running on SQL server 2012?
This doesn't seem to be clear enough from the official SSIS or SQL Server documentation.

I installed the latest versions of VS and .NET and SSIS and after creating a new project in VS2022 and selecting the target database as SQL2022 in the SSIS project after adding and editing the script task, the maximum available version for the target framework is 4.7.2. So there must be some implicit limitation on the compatibility of SSIS projects with .NET versions?

My questions are related to the process of installing new environments and selecting appropriate software versions so that the latest versions of SSIS and .NET custom components can run on them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSIS Script Keeps Reverting To .Net Framework 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629156/ssis-script-keeps-reverting-to-net-framework-4-5) As you are on 2012, you should be able to use a higher version, but it's been some time since I used 2012 now (it is completely unsupported after all, and has been for almost 2 years)

Comment: Although note that the actual version which is used is always whatever is installed (you can only have one 4.x installed), it's only the target version which changes.

Answer (score 1):

[.Net Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) is the maximum supported ... product.

As the fine commenters have noted, the runtime used is what is installed on the box. But, it will never be [core/.NET #](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET)